# Download File from Dropbox folder in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropbox, rest-client

I am trying and failing to download a single file from a "open for public" dropbox folder which a 3rd party created for others to use. I am trying to use this within my Ruby On Rails Application (file is changing but folder stays the same all the time).

I want to:

1. List all files in that public folder
2. Make sure that there is only this one file
3. ... and this file has the appropriate filename (ending in .xlsx in my case -> an Excel file)
4. Download the file (e.g. using RestClient gem)
5. Save as an attachment to a new database record (Record is existing already and is used inside the app)

Thanks for any hints on how to proceed here! I Than plan to update the file with a cron-job daily.

Its kind of an API to the public :-)

- Thought there must be a simple gem to interact with dropbox folders but couldnt't find any.
- I used Rest-Client to open the dropbox folder and Nokogiri to parse the content but cant work through the glibberish produced. I gave up after an hour of work and decided to ask here!

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does offer [a public Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), but it doesn't offer an official SDK for Ruby in particular, but you can either use [the Dropbox API HTTPS endpoints](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) directly, or via [a third party library](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks) if there is one that works for your use case.

Exactly how you would accomplish this would depend on the specifics of the scenario so you may want to read through some [guides](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference) first to get started, e.g.: [Getting Started](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started) and [File Access](https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-file-access-guide).

For instance, depending on how you have access to the content (e.g., directly via a folder in a connected account, or via a shared link, etc.) some of the following endpoints may be useful:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file

[The Dropbox API v2 Explorer](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/) can also be a useful tool for trying out Dropbox API calls.

Comment: reading through your stuff, I dont know how to proceed specifically. Do I need to authenticate to download a simple file from a dropbox folder? API sounds cool.

Comment: Yes, to access the contents of a Dropbox account directly, you'll need to be authorized to connect to that account. If you've been given a shared link to the relevant content though, you do not need access to the original account.